# Rename-item Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName comp1,comp2 -ScriptBlock {Get-ChildItem F:\sktest\*.txt | ForEach-Object{
$a=$_.fullname
$b=$a.Substring(0,($a.Length-4))+"_old.txt" | %{
   Rename-Item -path $a -NewName $b}
}}
```

While using the above piece of code to rename files(e.g. abc.txt to abc_old.txt),powershell is throwing "Cannot bind argument to parameter 'NewName' because it is null." error.

When i print the results of $a and $b before the last pipeline, the result is coming as expected.However it is failing with the rename-item cmdlet at the end. Please let me understand the mistake im doing here.

Comment: you do not need the second `foreach`  (alias `%`)

Comment: i tested without foreach as well and get same error as below-                                                                Cannot bind argument to parameter 'NewName' because it is null.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Rename-Item], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameItemC
   ommand

Comment: you may have a typo i'm writing the working script as an answer

Comment: thanks a lot Kayasax! the problem occured because i put a pipe before rename-item,when i removed the pipe it worked fine...although i have a bad explaination that i read in some blog that if the properties that a preceding cmdlet outputs do not match the input parameters of the final cmdlet,we need to use foreach in that case..thanks for taking your time to help me fix it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you dont need the second foreach block.
(remove -whatif to effectively rename file)

```
Get-ChildItem c:\temp\*.txt | ForEach-Object{
    $a=$_.fullname
    $b=$a.Substring(0,($a.Length-4))+"_old.txt" 
    Rename-Item -path $a -NewName $b -whatif
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, there was an extra ForEach. I recommend not trying to cram commands into one line.  The line $b also is more reproducible when keeping the input object, an object instead of changing it to a string. Basically, the code would break if C:\SomeWorkingDir\MyFile.LongExtension were the target for he rename.  The following accounts for this previously mentioned items.

```
$Path = C:\SomeWorkingDir
Get-ChildItem $Path |
ForEach-Object {
    $a = $_.fullname
    $b = $_.BaseName + "_old.txt"
    Rename-Item -path $a -NewName $b
} # end foreach. Also end Get-ChildItem
```